# How to give a solid asymptotic for 3-smooth numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I recently asked this question, and someone told that these are the 3-smooth numbers.

Link: http://oeis.org/A003586

I was looking for a solid asymptotic for a(n)(if I go with n to infinity), but the formula they are giving there is just too "extraordinary" for me(can't really prove that for homework, they won't believe I figured it out:) ).

Can you help me on giving a bit easier, and not so solid asymptotic for this problem? (3 smooth number means that it has the form of 2^i*3^j, where i and j are both bigger than 0(and integers).

a(n) means the number of natural numbers that are lower than n, and are 3-smooth numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to $x$ there are
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left\lfloor\log_2\frac{x}{3^j}\right\rfloor
$$
3-smooth numbers. You can approximate this as
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \log_2\frac{x}{3^j}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\log_2x-j\log_23\right)
$$
where the summand is roughly a triangle of height $\log_2x$ and base $\log_3x$ for a total area of about
$$
\frac{\log_2x\log_3x}{2}=\frac{(\log x)^2}{2\log2\log3}.
$$

Does this suffice?